# Why doGET is being called instead of doPOST?

Tags: jsp

I am testing the form based Security authentication with Servlet/JSP. I am simply running the servlet directly and it should ask me for the Login authentication as per the web.xml file. But it simply enters the doGET method everytime. And yes, I have made changes to add the "role" 'users' in the tomcat-users.xml file. I am new to J2EE. So please bear with my stupid questions.

Here is the Login.jsp

```
<form method="post" action="j_security_check">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>User name: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="j_username"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password: </td>
        <td><input type="password" name="j_password"></td>
    </tr>
</table>`enter code here`
<input type="submit"    value="Login">  
</form>
```

Here is the Servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/SecurityCheck")
public class SecurityCheck extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.getWriter().println("I went to doGET");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.getWriter().println("success........");
    }

}
```

and here is the web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Security check</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/SecurityCheck/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>users</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
      <form-login-page>/Login.jsp</form-login-page>
      <form-error-page>/Faliure.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
  </login-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: *" I am simply running the servlet directly"* What do you mean by that? Are you typing the servlet's URL in the browser? Or are you actually reaching it by a POST request from some other form?

Comment: On the servlet page, I am just doing "Run server" by right clicking on it. I am using Eclipse IDE.

Comment: If your servlet is being called via a GET method, it will run the `doGet()` method. Create another HTML page in your root context, create a `<form>` in it with `method="post"` and `action="SecurityCheck"`, containing a button. Click it and see what method gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you declare the security role in the web.xml as well?

```
   <security-role>
      <role-name>users</role-name>
   </security-role>
```

If you're accessing your servlet like

```
   SecurityCheck/myServlet
```

you want to be prompted with a login screen correct? You are making a resource request via the GET method (default). This should be added to your security constraint > web resource collection tag.

```
   <http-method>GET</http-method>
   <http-method>POST</http-method>
```

Currently, only POST methods within the SecurityCheck path will be prompted for login if no user is authenticated yet.

Comment: Tried it, but still the same weird thing.

Comment: Thanks... now atleast I am getting the Login page, but the request is still going through the GET method. How can I do it through POST. I am just following the same thing as in this video : [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6XDJ4cFW9c8&list=PLSM8fkP9ppPq4sCyQPfKXxKAo4R1ejPDN&index=4). I don't know how it is working for him and not me. :(

Comment: Sorry. In the video he is having doGET. My bad.

Comment: If you access your servlet directly from the browser, the default call will always be GET. If you want to access your servlet via POST, you can try creating a <form> on another page and make the action="<path-to-myServlet>/myServlet" and method="post". Upon submitting this form, you will access the servlet via POST method. Is there a reason why you want it to pass through POST? Why not use GET?

Comment: Yes. Everything is working fine now. Thanks for your inputs. I'll try the POST method by making a form. There is no reason for using POST. I am just learning stuff. :)

Comment: You'll get the hang of it soon :) Kindly accept the answer if it's not too much :)